# Custom collection in media manager?

Tags: plugin-development, attachments, media-library

I'm working on a plugin that extends the media manager, load JSON based input data to render an own collection of images and may upload them to my wordpress media library.

So far I got my own tab, can put my own content to the frame but the only way I figured out to put my JSON data to the content was with "basic" jQuery stuff.

Primary I'm looking for the possibility to make my own attachement-collection and mostly handle it with the given function to make it look like in the "gallery"-tab for example. To have the images clickable and the selected ones uploadable to my library.

Here is a snippet of my extended content view so far:

```
wp.media.view.CustomView = wp.media.View.extend({
className: 'media-fap',

initialize: function() {
    this.input = "asdf";
    var el = this.$el;

    jQuery.getJSON( "http://192.168.11.47/fap/wp-json/image", function( data ) {
        console.log("get json");

        var output = '<ul>';
        for(i in data) {
            var item = data[i];

            output += '<li><img src="' + item.thumbnail + '"></li>';
        }

        output += '</ul>';

        el.append(output);
    });

    // insert it in the view
    //this.$el.append("this.input");
    console.log("custom content");

    // re-render the view when the model changes
    this.model.on( 'change:custom_data', this.render, this );
},

render: function(){
    this.input.value = this.model.get('custom_data');
    return this;
},

custom_update: function( event ) {
    this.model.set( 'custom_data', event.target.value );
}
});
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this?